# Ошибки в android-support-v7-appcompat

Tags: android, eclipse

Внезапно появились ошибки в этой папке в workspace, и теперь два моих проекта показывают красный восклицательный знак.
Как решить проблему?

**Обновление**

v4 у меня не импортирован. В основном ошибки такого рода:

> No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.

Проекты - это программы для определения дня недели по дате. Не помню, после чего появились, но  вроде докачивал sdk api 15, но я его удалил:

> [2014-10-28 18:25:26 - DateToDay1]
> Found 2 versions of
> android-support-v4.jar in the
> dependency list,   [2014-10-28
> 18:25:26 - DateToDay1] but not all the
> versions are identical (check is based
> on SHA-1 only at this time).
> [2014-10-28 18:25:26 - DateToDay1] All
> versions of the libraries must be the
> same at this time. 
>  [2014-10-28
> 18:25:26 - DateToDay1] Versions found
> are:    [2014-10-28 18:25:26 -
> DateToDay1] Path:
> D:\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v4.jar

Comment: итак, битва экстрасенсов началась!
Может напишите, какую ошибку выдаёт?(в eclips вкладка Problems)

Comment: @dante4001 сложно что-то сказать. Конкретизируйте хоть: что за проекты, посл чего ошибки посылались и т.п.

Comment: Как я и сказал, у вас ругается на разные версии либы. Удалите её из одного проекта. Удалите один референс.

Comment: А с какой версией SDK собираете? Новую v7 нужно собирать с 21, иначе ресурсы вроде android:colorAccent действительно нигде объявлены не будут.

Comment: Так, ну вроде с этим разобрался, но теперь возникла другая проблема - R.java моего проекта не хочет добавлять в себя кое-какие обновления(да, знаю, что в нем нельзя ничего редактировать).

Вот к примеру строка - R.color.margin

Ругается на margin

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас один проектов включает другой, а ругается на версии либы, то удалите джарник android-support-v4.jar из дочернего проекта, оставьте только в базовом.

Comment: Я не могу найти эти референсы.

Comment: В папке libs, в настройках проекта Java build path.

Comment: А как быть с appcompact? Она всё время ругается на то, что не может что-то найти.

Comment: @dante4001 он ругается, что у вас одна библиотека с двумя разными версиями подключена.

Comment: И что делать?
Я вот создал отдельный пустой workspace, импортировал туда appcompact v7, и всё равно ошибки кидает.

Comment: папочки libs смотрите и настройках билда проекта, писал же уже

Comment: В папке libs проекта пусто, в настройках билда проекта в AndroidDependencies ругается на appcompact v7.

Answer (score 1):

appcompact и прочее нужно обновлять до самой последней версии, если не ошибаюсь, то sdk 21.0.2 исправит более-менее все баги.

Answer (score 1):

В эклипс восклицательный знак означает проблемы с подключаемыми модулями/библиотеками.
Правой кнопкой по проекту, `properties-android`, там ниже списка `SDK API` есть список библиотек.
Если они красным цветом выделены, можно их попробовать почистить и пересобрать **!!!ПО ОТДЕЛЬНОСТИ!!!**, не в коем случае не `Build All`, если не получается, можно скопировать нужную библиотеку в воркспейс и добавить ее еще раз в  этот проект.
Главное билдить и чистить проекты по одному, а не сразу.
Если у вас **R** файл не находится, попробуйте почистить проект, если не исправилось, то ошибка в одном из `xml` файлов или в `layout`е`. Вкладка **problems** вам в помощь.